# Overview of basic results about images and preimages

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, reference-request, online-resources, faq

Are there some good overviews of basic facts about images and inverse images of sets under functions?

Comment: This question is also asked in an effort to make search for duplicates easier, since questions like this are asked quite often. For a more detailed discussion see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967/would-organizer-posts-be-useful-welcome-here).

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746123/prove-that-ff-1-fx-fx, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061602

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608707, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834689

Answer (score 268):

I have no doubt that there are many useful online resources for these, but many such results are available here at MSE, together with their proofs.

I'll give a list of some basic results about images and preimages links to the posts, which have proofs here at MSE. I am making this CW, so feel free to add more identities and pointers to further useful questions and answers.
$\newcommand{\Map}[3]{{#1}\colon{#2}\to{#3}}\newcommand{\Img}[2]{{#1}[#2]}\newcommand{\Pre}[2]{{#1}^{-1}[#2]}$

If $\Map fXY$ is a function and $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$ are some set then the set
$$\Img fA=\{f(x); x\in A\}$$
is called the *[image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_%28mathematics%29)* of the subset $A$ and the set
$$\Pre fB=\{x; f(x)\in B\}$$
is called the *preimage* or *inverse image* of the subset $B$.

In the other words, we have
$$y\in\Img fA \Leftrightarrow (\exists x\in A)f(x)=y$$
and
$x\in\Pre fB \Leftrightarrow f(x)\in B$.

In the notation below we always assume $A,A_i\subseteq X$ and $B,B_i\subseteq Y$.

> - $A\subseteq \Pre f{\Img fA}$ and, if  $f$ is injective, then $A=\Pre f{\Img fA}$.

see [Proving that $C$ is a subset of $f^{-1}[f(C)]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/347880)
In fact, the equality is equivalent to the fact that $f$ is injective: [Show $S = f^{-1}(f(S))$ for all subsets $S$ iff $f$ is injective](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/261157) or [Is $f^{-1}(f(A))=A$ always true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/78110) Some counterexamples to the equality can be found in answers to [Why $f^{-1}(f(A)) \not= A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/368990)

> - $\Img f{\Pre fB}\subseteq B$ and, if $f$ is surjective, then $\Img f{\Pre fB}=B$.

For the first part see: [Need help for proving that: $f(f^{-1}(A)) ⊆ A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2119866) For the second part, see [Demonstrate that if $f$ is surjective then $X = f(f^{-1}(X))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/557764) or [Prove $F(F^{-1}(B)) = B$ for onto function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1030029).

> - The operation of taking images and preimages preserves inclusion, i.e. $A_1\subseteq A_2$ implies $\Img f{A_1}\subseteq \Img f{A_2}$ and $B_1\subseteq B_2$ implies $\Pre f{B_1}\subseteq\Pre f{B_2}$
> - Image of union of two sets is the union of their images, i.e. $\Img f{A_1\cup A_2}=\Img f{A_1}\cup\Img f{A_2}$.

See, for example, [Prove $f(S \cup T) = f(S) \cup f(T)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/231150)
or [Functions-Set Theory Proof that $f(C \cup D) = f(C) \cup f(D)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/285589)
or [How do I prove the following: $f(S\cup T) = f(S) \cup f(T)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/338699)
or [Maps - question about $f(A \cup B)=f(A) \cup f(B)$ and $ f(A \cap B)=f(A) \cap f(B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/239783)
or [Unions and Functions on Sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/123625)
or [The preimage of a subset](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1142461)

> - The same is true for arbitrary union: $$\Img f{\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i} = \bigcup_{i\in I} \Img f{A_i}.$$

See [Show that $\bigcup_i f(A_i) = f(\bigcup_i A_i)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/225293)

> - In the case of intersection, we only have one inclusion: $$\Img f{A_1\cap A_2}\subseteq \Img f{A_1} \cap \Img f{A_2}.$$ But if $f$ is injective, then $\Img f{A_1\cap A_2} = \Img f{A_1} \cap \Img f{A_2}$.

See, for example [Is this a valid proof of $f(S \cap T) \subseteq f(S) \cap f(T)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/228613)
or [Is this proof correct for : Does $F(A)\cap F(B)\subseteq F(A\cap B) $ for all functions $F$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/225333)
or [Prove $f(S \cap T) \subseteq f(S) \cap f(T)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/231145)
or [Do we have always $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/170725)
or [Maps - question about $f(A \cup B)=f(A) \cup f(B)$ and $ f(A \cap B)=f(A) \cap f(B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/239783)
or [Verifying a proposition on image and preimage: $f(A\cap B)\subseteq f(A)\cap f(B)$ and $f^{-1}(C\cap D)=f^{-1}(C)\cap f^{-1}(D)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/144870)
or [How to prove this? "For all sets $A,B\subseteq D$ and functions $f:D\mapsto R$, we have $f(A\cap B)\subseteq(f(A)\cap f(B))$."](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/939730)
or [$f(A \cap B)\subset f(A)\cap f(B)$, and otherwise?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1205840)

The part about injective functions can be found in
[Conditions Equivalent to Injectivity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/79287) or in
[Proving: $f$ is injective $\Leftrightarrow f(X \cap Y) = f(X) \cap f(Y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/79331)

A counterexample showing that equality is not true in general can be found here: [Do we have always $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/170725)

In fact, if this equality is true for all subsets $A_1,A_2\subseteq X$, then $f$ must be injective, see [To prove mapping f is injective and the other f is bijective](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/193191)

> - Again, the same claims hold for arbitrary intersection: $\Img f{\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i} \subseteq \bigcap_{i\in I} \Img f{A_i}$ and if $f$ is injective, then $\Img f{\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i} = \bigcap_{i\in I} \Img f{A_i}$.

See: [Inverse image of a union equals the union of the inverse images](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/174401) and [Proof for Image of Indexed Collection of Sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/594965)

> - Preimages preserve intersection: $\Pre f{B_1\cap B_2}=\Pre f{B_1} \cap \Pre f{B_2}$.

See, for example: [What are the strategies I can use to prove $f^{-1}(S \cap T) = f^{-1}(S) \cap f^{-1}(T)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/228711)
or [how to prove $f^{-1}(B_1 \cap B_2) = f^{-1}(B_1) \cap f^{-1}(B_2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/516374)
or [Verifying a proposition on image and preimage: $f(A\cap B)\subseteq f(A)\cap f(B)$ and $f^{-1}(C\cap D)=f^{-1}(C)\cap f^{-1}(D)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/144870)

> - The same is true for arbitrary intersections: $\Pre f{\bigcap_{i\in I}B_i} = \bigcap_{i\in I} \Pre f{B_i}$.

See: [Proving set equalities](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4188900)

> - Preimages preserve union: $\Pre f{B_1\cup B_2}=\Pre f{B_1} \cup \Pre f{B_2}$.

See: [Show that $f^{-1}(A \cup B) = f^{-1}(A) \cup f^{-1}(B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/357725)

> - Again, this is also true for union of more than just two sets: $$\Pre f{\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i} = \bigcup_{i\in I} \Pre f{B_i}.$$

See: [Union of preimages and preimage of union](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/141356)

We can also ask whether image and preimage preserve difference:

> - $\Img f{A_1}\setminus\Img f{A_2} \subseteq \Img f{A_1\setminus A_2}$, but the equality does not hold in general

See [Proving $f(C) \setminus f(D) \subseteq f(C \setminus D)$ and disproving equality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/511662). Equality holds for injective functions, see [If $f$ is 1-1, prove that $f(A\setminus B) = f(A)\setminus f(B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/944683). In fact, validity of the equality $\Img f{A_1}\setminus\Img f{A_2} = \Img f{A_1\setminus A_2}$
characterizes injectivity: [Does $f(X \setminus A)\subseteq Y\setminus f(A), \forall A\subseteq X$ imply $f$ is injective ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1319371).

> - $\Pre f{B_1}\setminus\Pre f{B_2}=\Pre f{B_1\setminus B_2}$

See [Proof of $f^{-1}(B_{1}\setminus B_{2}) = f^{-1}(B_{1})\setminus f^{-1}(B_{2})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1372833). As a consequence of this we get that the preimage of complement is complement of the preimage, see here: [How to approach proving $f^{-1}(B\setminus C)=A\setminus f^{-1}(C)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/553306), [Show that for any subset $C\subseteq Y$, one has $f^{-1}(Y\setminus C) = X \setminus f^{-1}(C)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1044550) and [Show $f^{-1}(A^c)=(f^{-1}(A))^c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1632840)

The image and inverse image for composition of maps can be expressed in a very simple way. For $\Map fXY$, $\Map gYZ$ and $A\subseteq X$, $C\subseteq Z$ we have

> - $\Img g{\Img fA}=\Img{g\circ f}A$
> - $\Pre f{\Pre gC}=\Pre{(g\circ f)}C$

See [Show that $(g \circ f)^{-1}(C) = g^{-1}(f^{-1}(C)).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3499136) and [Prove that if $Z\subseteq Y$, then $(g\circ f)^{-1}(Z)=f^{-1}(g^{-1}(Z)).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/360333)

Comment: [The amount of duplicates...](http://i.huffpost.com/gen/210699/thumbs/s-THE-RENT-IS-TOO-DAMN-HIGH-JIMMY-MCMILLAN-large.jpg)

Comment: @user18921 Corrected now. Thanks to [wj32](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/359694/revisions).

Comment: Yeeees getting this all in one place

Comment: Is there a similar list for stronger results when the map is continuous?

Comment: @plebmatician To be honest, I am not really sure what kind of properties you have in mind. In any case, I have mentioned this in [Calculus and analysis chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14150/2018/12/20), maybe somebody will notice it there.

Comment: I love the fact almost all of this can be deduced immediately from the adjunctions $f[-]\vdash f^{-1}[-] \vdash f_{*}[-]$.

Answer (score 53):

This big list is included in Appendix A of *Introduction to Topological Manifolds* by John M. Lee:

Let $f:X\to Y$ and $g:W\to X$ be maps, and suppose $R\subseteq W$, $S,S'\subseteq X$, and $T,T'\subseteq Y$.

- $T\supseteq f(f^{-1}(T))$.
- $T\subseteq T' \Rightarrow f^{-1}(T)\subseteq f^{-1}(T')$.
- $f^{-1}(T\cup T')=f^{-1}(T)\cup f^{-1}(T')$.
- $f^{-1}(T\cap T')=f^{-1}(T)\cap f^{-1}(T')$.
- $f^{-1}(T\setminus T')=f^{-1}(T)\setminus f^{-1}(T')$.
- $S\subseteq f^{-1}(f(S))$.
- $S\subseteq S' \Rightarrow f(S)\subseteq f(S')$.
- $f(S\cup S')=f(S)\cup f(S')$.
- $f(S\cap S')\subseteq f(S)\cap f(S')$.
- $f(S\setminus S')\supseteq f(S)\setminus f(S')$.
- $f(S)\cap T=f(S\cap f^{-1}(T))$.
- $f(S)\cup T\supseteq f(S\cup f^{-1}(T))$.
- $S\cap f^{-1}(T)\subseteq f^{-1}(f(S)\cap T)$.
- $S\cup f^{-1}(T)\subseteq f^{-1}(f(S)\cup T)$.
- $(f\circ g)^{-1}(T)=g^{-1}(f^{-1}(T))$.
- $(f\circ g)(R)=f(g(R))$.

Comment: found this while doing a problem from Lee's book.

Comment: Very nice! There is a similar theorems-exercises on the first chapter of Tom Apostol's mathematical analysis.

Answer (score 6):

The "online compendium of mathematical proofs" known as [ProofWiki](http://proofwiki.org) has most of these results -- with one or more proofs. (For the record, I am somewhat affiliated with that site.)

Most results regarding images and preimages should be in the [Mapping Theory category](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Category%3aMapping_Theory) (look under the "M").

Answer (score 6):

Here's interesting application of inverse image:

1. Given two functions: $ f : R \times R \rightarrow R, g : R \rightarrow 2, g=([n_0..n_1] \mapsto 1)$, the composition of them gives characteristic function $ h : R \times R \rightarrow 2$.
2. Use equation $h(x,y)=1$ to choose $1$ from $2=\{0,1\}$.
3. Once chosen, use inverse image to find all $(x,y)$ -pairs: Inverse image $g^{-1}(1)$ gives whole range $[n_0..n_1]$. Inverse image $ f^{-1} ([n_0..n_1]) $ is the interesting one.
4. Example of how this works is simply by choosing $f = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $g=([0..5]\mapsto 1)$ to get a (filled) circle with radius 5 from inverse image, distance function f, and simple range function g.
5. Example2: $f=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $g=([3..5]\mapsto 1)$ gives you circle with a hole.
6. Example3: $f=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $g=([r..r]\mapsto 1)$ gives you solutions to equation $x^2+y^2=r^2$ (with the caveat that the characteristic function is useless)
7. Key information is that inverse images can give more information about subsets defined via characteristic functions.