# Proving properties of maps between topological spaces

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm reading the section Maps between topological space from **Isham CJ. Modern differential geometry for physicists. World Scientific; 1999.**. Here he defines the map between two topological space  $$ f:X \to Y $$ Induces a map from $P(X)$ to $P(Y)$, which is defined on a subset $A \subset X$ as $$ f(A) := \{\:f(x) \in Y |\: x \in A \:\} $$  and has the properties

$$ 
f(A \cup B) = f(A) \cup f(B) 
\\ f(A \cap B) \subset f(A) \cap f(B) 
$$

On the other hand, the inverse map from $P(Y)$ to $P(X)$ is
$$
f^{-1}(A) = \{\: x \in X |\:f(x) \in A \:\}
$$
This map has the following two properties
$$ f^{-1}(A \cup B) = f^{-1}(A) \cup f^{-1}(B) 
\\ f^{-1}(A \cap B) = f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B) $$

**My objective is to start from the definition of the map and prove all of these 4 properties.**

### My take on the proof

Now, starting from the definition of the induced map I can prove the first property of the map
\begin{align}
f(A) &= \{\:f(x_1) \in Y |\: x_1 \in A \:\} \\
f(B) &= \{\:f(x_2) \in Y |\: x_2 \in B \:\} \\
\end{align}
So,
\begin{align}
f(A\cup B) &= \{\:f(x_3) \in Y |\: x_3 \in A \cup B \:\} 
\end{align}
Now, $x_3 \in A \cup B$ means $ x_3 \in A \text{ OR } x_3 \in B$. So,
\begin{align}
f(A\cup B) &= \{\:f(x_3) \in Y |\: x_3 \in A  \text{ OR } x_3 \in B \:\} \\
\implies f(A\cup B) &= \{\:f(x_3) \in Y |\: x_3 \in A \:\} \cup \{\:f(x_3) \in Y |\: x_3 \in A \:\} 
\\&= f(A) \cup f(B) 
\end{align}
Thats' how I prove the first property of the map. To prove the second property in the same spirit I do
\begin{align}
f(A\cap B) &= \{\:f(x_3) \in Y |\: x_3 \in A \cap B \:\} \\
\implies f(A\cap B) &= \{\:f(x_3) \in Y |\: x_3 \in A \text{ AND } x_3 \in B \:\} \\
\implies f(A \cap B) &= \{\:f(x_3) \in Y |\: x_3 \in A \:\} \cap \{\:f(x_3) \in Y |\: x_3 \in B \:\}\\
&= f(A) \cap f(B) \\
\end{align}
Similarly I can prove the two properties for the inverse map.

**I don't know how to get the subset relation for the second property.
Another concern is that, can this kind of logic be used to prove the properties for the maps?**

Comment: To prove subset relationships like $S\subset T$, it usually works to consider an element of $S$ and show it is also in $T$.

Comment: what is the map $P$ good for? I don't see how it contributes to anything.

Comment: @Zest $P(X)$ is the power set of $X$

Comment: I see, so essentially the claim is $X\to Y$ induces a map $\mathcal{P}(X)\to \mathcal{P}(Y)$.

Comment: The identity $f(A\cap B) = f(A)\cap f(B)$ is wrong in general and needs to be replaced by the weaker $f(A\cap B)\subset f(A)\cap f(B)$.

Comment: @LouisHainaut fixed the typo,

Comment: Note that at the end of your post you still "prove" this identity. This shows that reasoning with set equalities can be dangerous; unless the equality is obvious I suggest to prove such equalities by proving mutual inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a question about the [intersection of preimages](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516374/how-to-prove-f-1b-1-cap-b-2-f-1b-1-cap-f-1b-2). In fact, the containment you write is an equality.

Also, yes, your technique should work to prove the other two statements as well.