# Proof that $f^{-1}(\overline{A}∩B)⊆f^{-1}(\overline{A})∩f^{-1}(B)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Prove [$f^{-1}(\overline{A}∩B)⊆f^{-1}(\overline{A})∩f^{-1}(B)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RVdj.png)
Where f: P→Q and A and B are non empty subsets of Q

So far I have:
[$f^{-1}(\overline{A}∩B)⊆f^{-1}(\overline{A})∩f^{-1}(B)$

$f^{-1}(\overline{A}∩B)↔{x∈f^{-1}(\overline{A})∧x∈f^{-1}(B)}$

$f^{-1}(\overline{A}∩B)↔{x∈f^{-1}(\overline{A})}∧{x∈f^{-1}(B)}$

$f^{-1}(\overline{A}∩B)↔f^{-1}(\overline{A})∩f^{-1}(B)$

$f^{-1}(\overline{A}∩B)⊆f^{-1}(\overline{A})∩f^{-1}(B)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAHLr.png)


 but I'm unsure if this is the correct way to prove it
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that the theorem holds for any sets and you need not worry about the closure of the set

Comment: What is the point of linking to a picture of the formula you are correctly typesetting?

Comment: I'm very confused by your proof attempt: it seems to both begin and end with your goal, and it has implications where one or both sides of the connective are sets instead of propositions. Sorry but to me it seems completely incomprehensible

Answer (score 1):

Using the comment by @FShrike, suppose that $x \in f^{-1}( A \cap B )$. For some $y \in A \cap B$ we have $f(x) = y$. Notice that $y \in A$ and $y \in B$. Thus $x \in f^{-1}(A)$ and $x \in f^{-1}(B)$. That is to say $x \in f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B)$.

Answer (score 0):

You even have an equality since:
\begin{align*}
x\in f^{-1}(\overline{A}\cap B)
&\Leftrightarrow
f(x)\in\overline{A}\cap B
\Leftrightarrow
f(x)\in\overline{A}\land f(x)\in B \\
&\Leftrightarrow
x\in f^{-1}(\overline{A})\land f^{-1}(x)\in B
\Leftrightarrow
x\in f^{-1}(\overline{A})\cap B.
\end{align*}
Other answers can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516374/how-to-prove-f-1b-1-cap-b-2-f-1b-1-cap-f-1b-2).