# How to approach proving $f^{-1}(B\setminus C)=A\setminus f^{-1}(C)$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $A,B,C$ be sets such that $C\subseteq B$. Let $f: A \to B$ be a function.  Prove that $f^{-1} (B\setminus C)=A\setminus f^{-1} (C).$

I really need help with this proof problem. I'm not sure where to begin or what strategy to consider using.

Comment: If $\;A=\emptyset\;$ the claim's blatantly false (unless $\;B=C\;$_. Perhaps you forgot to add some condition on $\;A\;$ ?

Comment: This may depend on $f$ ? What is $f$ ?

Comment: Why vote down? People can't ask questions?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be leaving out the assumption that $\;f : A \to B\;$.

Here is one strategy: go from the set level to the element level by expanding the definitions (or defining properties), and then use the laws of logic to simplify.

The defining property of $\;\cdot^{-1}[\cdot]\;$ (yes, I'm using a slightly different notation for clarity) is
$$
(0) \;\;\; x \in f^{-1}[Y] \;\equiv\; f(x) \in Y
$$
for any $\;f : A \to B\;$, $\;x \in A\;$, and $\;Y \subseteq B\;$.

With this, the left hand side is rewritten like this, for any $\;x \in A\;$:
\begin{align}
& x \in f^{-1}[B \setminus C] \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"property $(0)$"} \\
& f(x) \in B \setminus C \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\setminus\;$"} \\
& f(x) \in B \land f(x) \not\in C \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"the range of $\;f\;$ is $\;B\;$, so $\;f(x) \in B\;$ is true"} \\
& f(x) \not\in C \\
\end{align}
Now do something similar with the right hand side, and draw your conclusion.