# Let $f: A \rightarrow B$, $D \subseteq A$, and $E \subseteq B$. Prove that $f^{-1}(B - E) \subseteq A - f^{-1}(E)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, proof-verification

Let $f: A \rightarrow B$, $D \subseteq A$, and $E \subseteq B$. Prove that $f^{-1}(B - E) \subseteq A - f^{-1}(E)$

Proof: Let $x \in f^{-1}(B-E)$, then $x \in f^{-1}(B)$ and $x \notin f^{-1}(E)$...
...

I know I want to show that $x \in A - f^{-1}(E)$, but how can I show that $x \in A$?

Comment: what about $D$? why did u mention it at all?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/553306/11994.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $A$ is the domain of $f$.  If it's anywhere, it's in there.

Also, a stronger result is true: $f^{-1}(B\setminus E)=f^{-1}(B)\setminus f^{-1}(E)$.