# Please help with the following questions or at least one of them.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

[image]

> **Problem 1.** Let $f \colon X\to Y$ be a function from the set $X$ to the set $Y$. For a subset $A\subset X$, let $f_*(A)=\{ y\in Y | \exists x\in A\text{ such that }f(x)=y\}$. Prove the following:
>   (i) The function $f \colon X\to Y$ is one-to-one if and only if $f_*(A\cap B)=f_*(A) \cap f_*(B)$ for all subsets $A$, $B$ of $X$.
>   (ii) The function $f \colon X\to Y$ is onto if and only if $Y\setminus f_*(A) \subseteq f_*(X\setminus A)$ for all subsets $A$ of $X$.

I've managed to prove the first part of problem 1. Stuck on the second. And completely clueless about problem 2.

My attempt:
Problem 1
i) Suppose $y\in f_*(A \cap B)$. Then $f_*(x)=y$ such that $x \in A \cap B$. Then, $x \in A$ and $x \in B$.
                Therefore, $y \in f_*(A)$ and $y \in f_*(B)$.
              This implies $y \in f_*(A) \cap f_*(B)$.
              Therefore, $f_*(A\cap B)=f_*(A) \cap f_*(B)$.

Comment: Can we see some work?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BTLmO.jpg

Comment: Problem 1(ii) might make a decent question, but you really should include the work you did in the question itself rather than a link from a comment--and even better, typeset all this so it's readable. Problem 2 seems unrelated. I'm not sure this is even the right site for it. The two problems certainly should not be combined in one question.

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one?).

Comment: Maybe you can find answer to at least some of your questions here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359693/overview-of-basic-results-about-images-and-preimages

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 0):

In your attempt you prove that $f_{*}\left(A\cap B\right)\subseteq f_{*}\left(A\right)\cap f_{*}\left(B\right)$
but not that $f_{*}\left(A\cap B\right)=f_{*}\left(A\right)\cap f_{*}\left(B\right)$
as you claim.

(i)$\Rightarrow$ From $A\cap B\subseteq A\wedge A\cap B\subseteq B$
it follows immediately that $f_{*}\left(A\cap B\right)\subseteq f_{*}\left(A\right)\cap f_{*}\left(B\right)$ (as you show in your attempt).
If $y\in f_{*}\left(A\right)\cap f_{*}\left(B\right)$ then $y=f\left(a\right)=f\left(b\right)$
for some $a\in A$ and some $b\in B$. Then $a=b\in A\cap B$ (because $f$ is one-to-one) so that
$y\in f_{*}\left(A\cap B\right)$.

(i) $\Leftarrow$ Let $u,v\in X$ with $y=f\left(u\right)=f\left(v\right)$.
For $A=\left\{ u\right\} $ and $B=\left\{ v\right\} $ we find $y\in f_{*}\left(A\right)\cap f_{*}\left(B\right)=f_{*}\left(A\cap B\right)$.
This implies that $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$ or equivalently that $u=v$.

(ii) $\Rightarrow$ Let $y\in Y-f_{*}\left(A\right)$. Then $y=f\left(x\right)$
for some $x\in X$. However, if $x\in A$ then $y=f\left(x\right)\in f_{*}\left(A\right)$
contradicting that $y\in Y\backslash f_{*}\left(A\right)$. We conclude
that $x\in X-A$ and consequently $y=f\left(x\right)\in f_{*}\left(X-A\right)$.

(ii) $\Leftarrow$Substituting $A=X$ leads to $Y-f_{*}\left(X\right)\subseteq f_{*}\left(X-X\right)=f_{*}\left(\emptyset\right)=\emptyset$.
So $Y=f_{*}\left(X\right)$, i.e. $f$ is onto.