# The preimage of a subset

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

If $A\subseteq B$ under what conditions is $f^{-1}(A) \subseteq f^{-1}(B)$, where $f^{-1}$ is the preimage, not  the inverse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, we should be clear about the definition of $f$.  Suppose $X, Y$ are sets and $f: X \to Y$ is a map.  Suppose $A, B \subseteq Y$ with $A \subseteq B$.

It's always true that $f^{-1}(A)$ is contained in $f^{-1}(B)$, and this should be clear by the definition of preimage.

$f^{-1}(A)$ is the stuff in $X$ that is mapped into $A$.  But since $A \subseteq B$, if stuff in $X$ is mapped into $A$, then that same stuff is mapped into $B$ because $A$ is a subset of $B$.  Then that means the stuff mapped into $A$ is a subset of the stuff mapped into $B$, i.e., $f^{-1}(A) \subseteq f^{-1}(B)$.

**Bonus question for you:**  If $A \subseteq B$, when is $f^{-1}(A) = f^{-1}(B)$?

Comment: If and only if $A=B$?

Comment: Well if $A = B$, it's definitely true, but $A$ doesn't have to equal $B$.  All we need is that $f^{-1}(B - A) = \emptyset$.  Think about it and tell me why.  **P.S. Here is a hint:** the preimage of a union is the union of the preimages.  So $f^{-1}(U \cup V) = f^{-1}(U) \cup f^{-1}(V)$ -- and before using this fact, you should prove it (it's easy using the definition of preimage).

Comment: $f^{-1}(A) =f^{-1}(B) \iff ${$x \in \mathbb{R}|f(x) \in A \cap B $}, Therefore

as long as $f^{-1}(A/B)$ and $ f^{-1}(B/A)$ is the empty set this is true.

Comment: I didn't see your hint, am i still correct?

Comment: @usainlightning I'm not sure what you mean with your $\iff$.  You have a statement on the left hand side, but a set on the right hand side.  Here is what I was looking for as a proof:  By my hint, since $B = A \cup (B - A)$, then $f^{-1}(B) = f^{-1}(A) \cup f^{-1}(B - A)$.  So if $f^{-1}(B - A) = \emptyset$, then we get $f^{-1}(B) = f^{-1}(A) \cup \emptyset = f^{-1}(A)$.

Comment: Yes sorry that is obvious

Comment: @usainlightning  Sorry I was mistaken in my last comment, which I deleted.  I said since $A \subseteq B$, $A - B = A$.  That's not true.  $A - B = \emptyset$ if $A \subseteq B$.