# Which of the following set inequalities are true?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $G_1,G_2\subseteq \Bbb R^2$ .Let $f:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2$. Then which are correct?

1. $f^{-1}(G_1\cup G_2)=f^{-1}(G_1)\cup f^{-1}(G_2)$
2. $f^{-1}(G_1^c)=(f^{-1}(G_1))^c$
3. $f(G_1\cap G_2)=f(G_1)\cap f(G_2)$
4. $G_1$ open and $G_2$ closed $\implies G_1+G_2 $ neither open nor closed.

I am getting $1,2$ as true. $3$ is false. If $W$ is open $x+W$ is open for all $x$. Thus $4$ is false. Are these correct?

Comment: That looks fine.

Comment: You might find some of such statements [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359693/overview-of-basic-results-about-images-and-preimages).

Comment: 1 and 2 are true for any function with any domain or range. The simplest counter-example to 3 is to suppose that $G_i=\{x_i\}$ for $i=1,2$ where $g_1\ne g_2$  but $f(g_1)=f(g_2)$. This also applies to functions in general.Note that 3 does hold when $f$ is 1-to-1.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it contains multiple questions and has no content of lasting value.