# Need help for proving that: $f(f^{-1}(A)) ⊆ A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I realised I needed to show more information, which I now did:

> $$f: X \rightarrow X \,\,\,\rm{and}\,\,\,\, A \subseteq X$$
>
> Proof that: $$f(f^{-1}(A)) \subseteq A$$

**This is my proof:**

By defintion:

$$f^{-1}(A)=\{x \in X\mid f(x) \in A\}$$ 
and

$$f(A)=\{f(x) \mid x \in A\} = \{y \in X \mid \exists x \in A: y=f(x)\} \subseteq X$$

Therefore we can end the proof by a final definition:\
$$f(f^{-1}(A))=\{y \in A: \exists x \in f^{-1}(A):y=f(x)\} \subseteq A$$

Is this a legit "proof"? And is it even a proof, when i only use definitions?

Comment: How do you know $y\in A$ in the last line?  You only have, from your definitions that $y\in X$.

Comment: Alright i see. I think that is my problem. How do i correct it?

Answer (score 7):

If $y \in f[f^{-1}[A]]$, this means that there is an $x \in f^{-1}[A]$ such that $f(x) = y$. But $x \in f^{-1}[A]$ means that $f(x) \in A$, so $y \in A$, which shows the inclusion. We just apply the two definitions you have given.

Also in words: $f^{-1}[A]$ are all points that are mapped by $f$ into $A$. So its image under $f$ is a subset of $A$.

Comment: Proof that: $f(f^{-1}(a)) \subseteq A:$

Let $y \in f(f^{-1}(A)$

If we can prove that $y \in A$ we would know that $f(f^{-1}(A) \subseteq A$

By definition:
$f^{-1}(A)=\{x \in X\mid f(x) \in A\}$

Therefore: $x \in f^{-1}(A): f(x)=y \ \wedge \ f(x) \in A $\\
$\Rightarrow y \in A$

Comment: Thanks for great response. I have tried to build on, what you showed me. Is this the correct way to formulate it? or did i miss something?

Comment: @Mathe It comes down to the same thing. You do need a quantifier $\exists x$ if you're using formulae. I prefer words above formulae, though. They express the ideas just as well. TO show the inclusion, you have to start with an arbitary $y$ in the left hand side, which you then introduce. Don't let variables drop out of thin air!

Answer (score 3):

In fact, one can prove that $f(f^{-1}(A))=f(X)\cap A$, then $f(f^{-1}(A))\subseteq A$.

**Proof:** Let $y\in f(X)\cap A$, then it exists $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$ and $x\in f^{-1}(A)$ hence $y\in f(f^{-1}(A))$. Conversely let $y\in f(f^{-1}(A))$ then $y\in A$ and $y\in f(f^{-1}(A))\subset f(X)$ thus $y\in f(X)\cap A$.

**About your proof:** In order not to be confused you should use a "policy of variables" like :

- $A$ is a subset of the codomain of $f$ (what is confusing is that, in this exercise $X=dom(f)=codom(f)$). In fact, equality $f(f^{-1}(A))=f(X)\cap A$ holds in general, for $f : X\to Y$

  $B$ is a subset of the domain of $f$

  $x$ is in the domain and $y$ in the codomain

in this respect, I would rewrite the last part of your solution as

> $$f(B)=\{f(x) \mid x \in B\} = \{y \in Y \mid \exists x \in B: y=f(x)\}$$
> Therefore we can end the proof by a final definition:
> $$f(f^{-1}(A))=\{y \in Y: \exists x \in f^{-1}(A):y=f(x)\} \subseteq A$$

Comment: It is interesting to note that, equality holds when f is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(f^{-1}(A)) = \{f(x)\mid x\in f^{-1}(A) \}$. Now for $x\in f^{-1}(A)$ we have $f(x)\in A$ by definition. So $\{f(x)\mid x\in f^{-1}(A) \}\subset A$.

Answer (score 1):

We just have to follow the definitions of function, subset, range, etc. See:

If $y\in f(f^{-1}(A))$, then there exists $x\in f^{-1}(A)$ such that $f(x)=y$. Since $x\in f^{-1}(A)$, there exists $y'\in A$ such that $f(x)=y'$.

Note that $y=y'$ by definition. Since $y'$ is in $A$, we have $y\in A$

Therefore, we have just proved $y\in f(f^{-1}(A))\implies y\in A$, which is equivalent to prove $f(f^{-1}(A))\subset A$