# Functions (set theory proof)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I don't know how to prove that $f(f⁻¹(Y))=Y$ iff $Y\subset Im(f)$

Thanks for your help!

Kind regards,

Phi.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Can your prove that, for any $f$ and any $Y$, we have $f(f^{-1}(Y)) \subset Y$?

Comment: You just have to lay down the definitions of the objects at hand : first, do you see how $f(f^{-1}(Y))\subset Y$ no matter what ? If you do, the only thing you have to prove is that the reverse inclusion is equivalent to $Y\subset Im(f)$. With this, it should be clearer how to proceed

Comment: Find many answers through: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359693/overview-of-basic-results-about-images-and-preimages

Comment: $\subseteq]$ $b\in f(f⁻¹(Y)) \rightarrow \exists a\in f⁻¹(Y)$ such that $f(a)=b$. So, $a\in f⁻¹(Y) \rightarrow f(a)\in Y$. So $f(f⁻¹(Y))\subset Y$

Comment: $\supseteq]$ $b\in Y$ and by hyp. ($Y\subset Im(f)$) $\rightarrow \exists a\in f⁻¹(Y)$ such that $f(a)=b$. So $a\in f⁻¹(Y)$ $\rightarrow$ $b=f(a)\in f(f⁻¹(Y))$. Then $Y\subset f(f⁻¹(Y))$.