# Proof of $f(A∩B)⊆f(A)∩f(B)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let there be a function $f:R→R$. Let $A$ & $B$  be two subsets of $R$. From my experience, I know that $f(A∩B)⊆f(A)∩f(B)$.

I don't know how to prove it. Also, are there certain conditions that the function $f$ or the sets $A$ & $B$ should follow for the above condition to be true?

Comment: I thought the $\subseteq$ should be $=$

Comment: @DHMO that's when $f$ is $1-1$.

Comment: In general, they are not equal.

Comment: @kobe Can you give me a counterexample?

Comment: Let $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x) = x^2$. If $A = [-1,0]$ and $B = [0,1]$, then $f(A\cap B) = f(\{0\}) = \{0\}$, but $f(A)\cap f(B) = [0,1] \cap [0,1] = [0,1] \neq \{0\}$.

Comment: @kobe Wow. I need to tune my intuition.

Comment: @DHMO $f(1)=2, f(2)=2$. Then $f \{ 1 \} \cap \{2\})=\emptyset$ but $f(\{1 \})\cap f(\{ 2\})=\{2\}$.

Comment: Also, similarly, $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=\sin(x)$. If $A=[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ and $B=[\pi/2, 3/2 \pi]$ then $f(A\cap B) = f(\pi/2)=1$, but $f(A)\cap f(B)$=[-1,1]=Range($f$), the entire range of the function.

Comment: You can find a few more posts about this (and similar) problems [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359693/overview-of-basic-results-about-images-and-preimages).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $y\in f(A\cap B)$. Then, by definition, there exists $x\in A\cap B$ such that $y=f(x)$;

- since $x\in A$, we have $y=f(x)\in f(A)$,
- since $x\in B$, we have $y=f(x)\in f(B)$.

Therefore $y=f(x)\in f(A)\cap f(B)$

Equality does not necessarily hold. Take $f\colon\{1,2\}\to\{0\}$ (the only possible map); take $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{2\}$. Then $f(A\cap B)=f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$, whereas $f(A)\cap f(B)=\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Definitions:

- $f(A \cap B) = \{f(x): x \in A \cap B\}$
- $f(A) \cap f(B) = \{f(x): x \in A\} \cap \{f(x): x \in B\}$

Now, $A \cap B \subseteq A$ and $A \cap B \subseteq B$.

Therefore, $f(A \cap B) \subseteq f(A)$ and $f(A \cap B) \subseteq f(B)$.

And the result follows from messing around with the logical definitions of $\subseteq$ and $\cap$.

Comment: I am asking how to logically prove this statement. I know the definitions.

Comment: @SalmanQureshi Am I clear enough?

Comment: Gimme a few minutes. I am trying to wrap my mind around it.

Answer (score 0):

A proof by elements is the safe way:

Let $y\in f(A\cap B)$. By definition, $y = f(x)$ for some $x\in A\cap B$. Therefore $f(x)\in A$ and $f(x)\in B$, which means $y=f(x)\in f(A)\cap f(B)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y \in f(A \cap B)$. Then $y=f(x)$ for some $x \in A \cap B$.

Since $x \in A$ and $y=f(x)$ we get $y \in f(A)$.

Since $x \in B$ and $y=f(x)$ we get $y \in f(B)$.

Therefore, $y \in f(A) \cap f(B)$.

This shows $f(A\cap B) \subseteq f(A) \cap f(B)$.

Answer (score 0):

Directly by definition you can prove it.

Let $y \in f(A \cap B)$. (This is because $X \subset Y$ means every element of $X$ is of $Y$; so to prove $X \subset Y$ we take an arbitrary one out of $X$ to see if that one is in $Y$.) Then by definition there is some $x \in A \cap B$ ensuring $y = f(x)$. Then note that $x \in A \cap B$ implies $x \in A$ and $x \in B$, implying that $f(x) \in f(A)$ and $\in f(B)$. So $y \in f(A) \cap f(B)$.