# Continuity Implications in any topological space

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

> Let $f:(X,\tau_1)\to (Y,\tau_2)$ be a function. TFAE :
>
> a) $f$ is continuous on $X$
>
> b) $\forall O \in \tau_2 $ $f^{-1}(O) \in \tau_1$
>
> c) $\forall F$ closed in $Y$, $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed in $X$

In many proofs I've seen that in *a $\Rightarrow$b* part : $x \in f^{-1}(O) \Rightarrow$ $f(x) \in O \in \tau_2$

**1)** How can we say $x \in f^{-1}(O) \Rightarrow$ $f(x) \in O \in \tau_2$ above? We don't know $f$ is surjective or not?

So $O \in V(f(x))$ -nbd of $f(x)$- , $f^{-1}(O) \in V(x)$

**2)** It is clear $O \in V(f(x))$ but I didn't understand how we said that $f^{-1}(O) \in V(x)$

And in *b $\Rightarrow$c* and *c $\Rightarrow$a*  parts :

$F^C=O$, $f^{-1}(O)=f^{-1}(Y\setminus F)=$ $X\setminus f^{-1}(F)$

**3)** How did we say $f^{-1}(Y\setminus F)=$ $X\setminus f^{-1}(F)$, again we dont know $f$ is surjective or not. It is valid if $f$ is surjective like above one, isn't it?

Could someone illuminate me please?

Comment: Define $V(x)$ for us, please. The set of “neighbourhoods” of $x$, I think. But what then is a neighbourhood of $x$?  And continuous is defined as local continuity at each point?  Many take 2. to be the definition.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Since I have indicated $V(f(x))$ is nbd of $f(x)$ I have not indicated $V(x)$ is nbd of $x$ again. I know b and c are generally being used as definition bu it was my final exam question. It is not written what then is a nbd of $x$, also I couldn’t see why in some websites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f^{-1}(O)=\{x\in X\ |\ f(x)\in O\}$ means the inverse image of $O$ under $f$, **not** the inverse of $f$ evaluated in an element (note that $O$ is a subset of $X$, not an element of $X$). So you don't need to know anything about $f$ (except for it being a function with $O$ a subset of its domain).

1. If $x \in f^{-1}(O)$, then $f(x) \in O$ by definition. $O$ is open, so $O\in\tau_2$.
2. $O \in V(f(x))$ implies $f^{-1}(O) \in V(x)$, because $f(x)\in O$ and $O$ is obviously a neighborhood (of $f(x)$), so by definition of continuity of $f$ we get that there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f(U)\subseteq O$, which is equivalent to writing $U\subseteq f^{-1}(O)$, so $f^{-1}(O)\in V(x)$.
3. Again by a [property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359693/overview-of-basic-results-about-images-and-preimages) of the inverse image: $f^{-1}(Y\setminus F)=f^{-1}(Y)\setminus f^{-1}( F)=X\setminus f^{-1}(F)$.

Comment: Thank you very very much. I have been considering $f$ as a function. Your answer is very beneficial for me

Comment: Why -1? I ve given +1. Is there any mistake? It looks true?

Comment: @esrabasar No need to worry. Someone downvoted all my questions and most of my answers, so the downvote is not due to the content, else he would certainly write a comment about what would be wrong with my answer.

Comment: It is really weird. You can contact with stackexchange. Have a nice day :)