# Let $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ be a function, $A, A_1, A_2$ subsets of $X$ and $B, B_1, B_2$ subsets of $Y$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ be a function, $A, A_1, A_2$ subsets of $X$ and $B, B_1, B_2$ subsets of $Y$.

a) Prove that $f^{-1}(Y)=X$

b) Prove that $f^{-1}(Y-B)=X-(f^{-1}(B))$

I could kind of see where I want to go with the first one though I'm not really sure where to start. I know that every element in $x$ gets mapped to $y$. So the inverse image of $Y$ must be $X$. I think that's right...

However the second proof I need help with entirely. Please and thanks.

Comment: Your attempt for the first is right. To prove the second you can try to show $x\in f^{-1}[Y-B] \iff x \in X-f^{-1}[B]$ for all $x\in X$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overview of basic results about images and preimages](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359693/overview-of-basic-results-about-images-and-preimages)