# Finding a counter example to one of four formulas for images and inverse images

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

So this is a question out of Real Analysis book that I'm working through, and I'm quite stuck.

Give a counterexample to one of the following four formulas for images and inverse images of sets (the other three are true)

1. $f(X_1 \cup X_2) = f(X_1) \cup f(X_2$),
2. $f^{-1}(Y_1 \cup Y_2) = f^{-1}(Y_1) \cup f^{-1}(Y_2)$,
3. $f(X_1 \cap X_2) = f(X_1) \cap f(X_2)$,
4. $f^{-1}(Y_1 \cap Y_2) = f^{-1}(Y_1) \cap f^{-1}(Y_2)$

I went through [Overview of basic results about images and preimages](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359693/overview-of-basic-results-about-images-and-preimages) and from other resources I can find online, all 4 of these are true... I can't figure out what I am missing.

Thanks for the help

Comment: The fifth property in your linked post is exactly about 3. check it out. Have you actually read that question completely?

Comment: I did, I must have skimmed and missed that.  However when going through that answer I fear I need some clarification.  If f is constant, then isn't it true that I don't have a bijection any longer?  In my text it states that a bijection is needed for an inverse function to exist, and since we're involving the inverses here I imagined we were assuming a bijection.

Comment: No, $f^{-1}[A] = \{x \in X: f(x) \in A\}$, there is no need for a bijection. The $f^{-1}[A]$ is just a  notation for a set.

Comment: Well that is precisely where my confusion was then.  My book had something like "... then the function is a bijection and has an inverse $f^{-1}(X)$ ". Thank you for the help!  Marking the answer below correct because it said essentially the same thing as you did.

Comment: Wait.. but copying from Wikipedia: "Not all functions have inverse functions. In order for a function f: X → Y to have an inverse it must have the property that for every y in Y there must be one, and only one x in X so that f(x) = y. This property ensures that a function g: Y → X will exist having the necessary relationship with f.". So f cannot be a constant function and still have an inverse.

Comment: $f^{-1}[A]$ has meaning whether $f$ has an inverse or not. It does **not** imply that the inverse of $f$ exists.

Comment: ahh okay, that distinction is important.  I really appreciate your help in understanding this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 is false, if F is a contant map and $X_1, X_2$ disjoint.
Exercise.  Prove for 3 that the
left hand side is a subset of the right hand side.

Comment: See my comments above.