# Borel measurable function $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

Tags: measure-theory, borel-measures

In some old books I found the following definition:

"Given $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $f$ is a Borel measurable function if $f^{-1}(B)$ is a Borel set [of X] for any open set $B \subseteq \mathbb{C}$."

My question is: if we consider the Borel $\sigma-$algebra for $X$ and also for $\mathbb{C}$, is enough to check the condition of the definition to show that a function is measurable with respect to these two $\sigma-$algebras?

I would be truly grateful if you could give some references.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  A hint: the preimage preserves unions, intersections and complements.See [Overview of basic results about images and preimages](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359693/overview-of-basic-results-about-images-and-preimages).

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking about that, but I was not pretty sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Let $X$, $Y$ non-empty sets, $A$ a $ \sigma-$ algebra on $X$, $B$ a $ \sigma-$ algebra on $Y$ and $f:X \to Y$ a mapping. If $C$ is a collection of subsets of $B$ such that $\sigma(C)=B$, then we have:

$f$ is $(A,B)-$ measurable $ \iff f^{-1}(M) \in A$ for all $M \in C$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have just found this result in "Measure Theory" by Donald Cohn :)

Comment: .....   a very fine book ....