# Proving set equalities

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to solve the below problem.

> Let $f:X\to Y$ be a map of set.
>
> For $B\subset Y$ we define $f^{-1}(B)=\{x\in X\,|\,f(x)\in B\}$.
>
> Show
> that $$f^{-1}(Y-B)=X-f^{-1}(B)\;\;,\quad
> \textstyle 
> f^{-1}\Bigl(\bigcup_{i\in I} B_i\Bigr)=\bigcup_{i\in I}
> f^{-1}(B_i)\;\;, \quad \text{ and }\;\;
> f^{-1}\Bigl(\bigcap_{i\in I} B_i\Bigr)=\bigcap_{i\in I}
> f^{-1}(B_i)\;\;.$$

Here is my attempt.

> (a) For any $x \in X$, we have:
> \begin{align*}
> x \in f^{-1} (Y - B) & \iff f(x) \in Y - B \\
> & \iff f(x) \not \in B \\
> & \iff x \not \in f^{-1} (B) \\
> & \iff x \in X - f^{-1} (B)
> \end{align*}
> So $f^{-1} (Y - B) = X - f^{-1} (B)$.
>
> Furthermore, we have:
> \begin{align*}
> x \in f^{-1} \left(\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} B_i\right) & \iff f(x) \in \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} B_i \\
> & \iff \exists i \in I, \; f(x) \in B_i \\
> & \iff \exists i \in I, \; x \in f^{-1} (B_i) \\
> & \iff x \in \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} f^{-1} (B_i)
> \end{align*}
> So $f^{-1} \left(\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} B_i\right) =  \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} f^{-1} (B_i)$.
>
> Finally, we have:
> \begin{align*}
> x \in f^{-1} \left(\bigcap\limits_{i \in I} B_i\right) & \iff f(x) \in \bigcap\limits_{i \in I} B_i \\
> & \iff f(x) \in B_i, \; \forall i \in I \\
> & \iff x \in f^{-1} (B_i), \; \forall i \in I \\
> & \iff x \in \bigcap\limits_{i \in I} f^{-1} (B_i)
> \end{align*}
> So $f^{-1} \left(\bigcap\limits_{i \in I} B_i\right) = \bigcap\limits_{i \in I} f^{-1} (B_i)$, as desired.

How does this look?

Comment: It looks correct. Congratulations !