# Image and preimage definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

I got the following very basic question:

> Why is an image - in contrast to a preimage - defined by using the existential quantifier?

Let $f\colon A \to B$ be a mapping and $M$ a subset of $A$ and $N$ a subset of $B$. Then, the image of $M$ can be defined as:

1. $f(M)=\{y\in B: \exists x \in M:(x)=y\}$

and the preimage of N as:

2. $f^{-1}(N)=\{x\in A:() \in N\}$.

Best and thank you very much,

Niki

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave the definition that you're working with. The image of a function $f\colon X\to Y$ is usually not defined with an existential quantifier, it's defined as the set $\{f(x)\mid x\in X\}$.

Comment: sorry, you are right - I have updated my post. In the proofs i have seen, the above definitions are assumed. e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359693/overview-of-basic-results-about-images-and-preimages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ were simply a relation instead of a function, then both definitions would need an existential quantifier. However, the definition of a function is that given $x\in A$, there is one and only one corresponding element of $B$, and that element is given the name $f(x)$. So there's no need for an existential quantifier in the definition of $f^{-1}(N)$, since there's already a notation for "that other object that must exist for $x$ to be in $f^{-1}(N)$".

Comment: Thank you very much, Greg. That was very helpful :)

Comment: Dear @Greg, just a quick follow-up question: That means that the following definition is equivalent with $^−1$()={∈:()∈}: $^−1$()={∈:∃!y y∈: ()=}, right?

Comment: It seems to be (though unnecessarily complicated)

Comment: alright, thank you very much:)